# Нужно найти два повторяющегося символа в строке регуляркой

Tags: javascript

На вход функции подается строка, нужно написать регулярку, которая обрабатывает эту строку, таким образом, что происходит поиск только числа с плавающей запятой.
Если попадается точка или минус больше чем один раз выбрасывать false.
Например если на вход идет строка  1.1.1.1 то выкидываем false, а если 1.2 или 5.6 или 3 то тогда возвращаем true

Answer (score 0):

Все очень и очень просто: давайте будём проверять регуляркой есть ли такой отрезок в строке, где с начала идёт "." тогда N цифр а тогда еще одна "." или "-" тогда N цифр а тогда еще один "-" тогда строка не валидна.

Также добавил специальные проверки, когда у строки не только цифры, когда идут символы "-." подрят и когда число оканчивается на "." :

```js
function check(str) {
  const regexp = /\.[0-9]*\.|\-[0-9]*\-/g;
  const regexpIsNumber = /[^-0-9.]/g;
  const regexpSpecials = /-\.|\.$/g;
  
  return !regexp.test(str) && !regexpIsNumber.test(str) && !regexpSpecials.test(str);
}

const strings = ["1.1.1.1", "1.2", "5.6", "3", "3a.1", "-2", "-3-4-5", "-.1", "-0.1", "1."];

for (let str of strings) {
  console.log(`String ${str} is ${check(str) ? "valid" : "invalid"}`);
}
```

Comment: А если значение `-3-4-5`? В задаче про минусы тоже сказано

Comment: хорошо учтём и их)

Comment: `.1`, `-.1`, `1.` и `-1.` вполне валидные способы задать значение в JavaScript

Comment: я понимаю, что они валидны в js, но я исходил из математического представления чисел :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такое выражение:

`^-?\d+(?:[.]\d+|)$` -> [Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/aevagW/1)

Если нужно включить `.1`, `-.1`, `1.` и `-1.` (валидное представление в JavaScript), то такой вариант:

`^-?(?:\.\d+|\d+\.?\d*)$` -> [Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/aevagW/2)